# F# linq - How to filter for only unique values?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, f#

my seq linq is

```
<@ db.Dictionaries
|> Seq.filter(fun x -> x.ID_Line = l1 || x.ID_Line = l2) @>
|> fun pquery ->
    <@ seq { for cd in db.DeltaCompares do
                for cl1 in %pquery do
                    for cl2 in %pquery do
                        yield
                            if cd.IID1 = cl1.IID && cd.IID2 = cl2.IID then
                                Some(cl1, cl2)
                            else None } @>
    |> query |> Seq.choose id 
    |> Seq.collect(fun a -> [fst a; snd a])
    |> List.ofSeq
```

but here I need only unique values here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Seq.distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353698.aspx), or [`Seq.distinctBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340464.aspx) will do what you want.

Presumably the query function can handle them, if you use it inside the quotation - but don't quote me on that.